# Evaluating if MethodExpression attribute is set (getting PropertyNotFoundException)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, conditional-statements, composite-component, methodexpression

I have a UI component with a MethodExpression attribute `changeListener`:

```xml
<composite:interface>
  <composite:attribute name="changeListener" required="false" method-signature="void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)" />
  ..
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>

  <p:remoteCommand name="ajaxOnChange"
                             update="#{cc.attrs.onChangeUpdate}"
                             oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.onchange}"
                             actionListener="#{cc.attrs.changeListener}" />
  ..
</composite:implementation>
```

This `changeListener` attribute is an optional method expression used as **actionListener** in the `remoteCommand` and I want to render the `<p:remoteCommand>` ONLY IF the `changeListener` attribute has been set.

I have tried several ways to check whether the attribute is set or not, especially:

```xml
<c:if test="#{! empty cc.attrs.changeListener}">
```

and

```xml
<p:remoteCommand rendered="#{cc.attrs.changeListener != null}" />
```

But I get a javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException because it tries to evaluate the attribute as a property instead.

How can I evaluate whether the optional method attribute is set or not ?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You was in the right direction with `<c:if>` already. The `rendered` one is never going to work. You only need to check if the [EL expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getValueExpression%28java.lang.String%29) is been set instead of actually evaluating the whole EL expression as a value expression and checking if its result is not empty, which would of course fail if the EL expression represents a method expression.

```
<c:if test="#{not empty cc.getValueExpression('changeListener')}">
     ...
</c:if>
```

This solution is however somewhat scary: you're grabbing the method expression as a value expression here. However, as long as you don't actually evaluate the enclosed EL expression (like as what your initial `#{cc.attrs.changeListener}` attempt does under the covers), then there's nothing at matter. There's no other clean way as there's nothing like `UIComponent#getMethodExpression()` in JSF API.